# Getting multiple Configuration Values into a Command Line script

Tags: teamcity

Using TeamCity 9.1.4.

I'm trying to get some server hostnames into a Command Line script with Configuration Parameters. I want each option to contain multiple hostnames.

My configuration:

```
vanmain => rad-ecr1,rad-ecr2,rad-ecr3,rad-myecr,rad-balancer
tor => rad2-bal,rad2-ecr1,rad2-ecr2,rad2-myecr
fvcdc => rad-fvcdc,rad-balancer
bccfa => rad-bccfa
```

When I select `fvcdc` in a build, I receive the following error message:

> One of entered values 'rad-fvcdc' is not one of valid select item values: rad-ecr1,rad-ecr2,rad-ecr3,rad-myecr,rad-balancer,rad2-bal,rad2-ecr1,rad2-ecr2,rad2-myecr,rad-fvcdc,rad-balancer,rad-bccfa

How do I get the values into my script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dunkan,
I successfully reproduced your issue and was able to find out the root cause of it.
On my virtual installation I created a build with `select` type parameter, let's name it `HostValue`. Next, in Items field I copy/pasted values from your initial post and tried to reproduce the problem -- but executing the build was successful. Then I decided to reconfigure parameter and toggled `Allow multiple` checkbox, and viola, same error message as you got!
If you read small text below `Value separator` field, you will see, that default value is comma: `,` and as your values contain this symbol you got an error.

So, to solve this problem I can suggest you these variants:

1. If you don't need multiple choices, you can just turn off this feature and everything should work.
2. Replace default `Value separator` with custom one, for example `<SEP>`. Then whenever you will select multiple values for this parameter you will get something like:

   `"rad-ecr1,rad-ecr2,rad-ecr3,rad-myecr,rad-balancer"<SEP>"rad2-bal,rad2-ecr1,rad2-ecr2,rad2-myecr"<SEP>"rad-fvcdc,rad-balancer"`
3. Replace comma in your values with some other separator, for example `|` or `:`. In this case it would look like:

   `"rad-ecr1:rad-ecr2:rad-ecr3:rad-myecr:rad-balancer","rad-fvcdc:rad-balancer"`

After that you can use the value of this parameter as usual `%HostValue%` and parse depending on which variant you choose.
Maybe the error message from server could be a little bit clearer. Hope it will help you.

Also I would like to recommend you my plugin [teamcity-web-parameters](https://github.com/grundic/teamcity-web-parameters). It will allow you to create dynamic select values from external web service.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this thread: https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206843785-How-to-specify-empty-value-for-Typed-Parameter -- looks very similar to your question.

Comment: Unfortunately not. rad-fvcdc is in the list of valid select values that it prints in the error message.